# Java Overridden method visibility scope

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class, visibility

How is the following program correct?

```
abstract class Calculate  
{  
    abstract int multiply(int a, int b);  
}  
   
public class Main  
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
        int result = new Calculate()  
        {      
            @Override  
            int multiply(int a, int b)  
            {  
                return a*b;  
            }  
        }.multiply(12,32);  
        System.out.println("result = "+result);  
    }  
}
```

We are changing the scope of the overridden method here.It is not public anymore and it should of default scope.Is the scope change of overridden method allowed?

Comment: Why should it not be public anymore? It was package private before and this didn't change.

Comment: can we create abstract class object like this?

Comment: where are you changing any scope?

Comment: Yes, as you can see. This creates an object of a subclass.

Comment: @dan but there is not subclass here,right? new Calculate(), is not a subclass

Comment: This is not "abstract class object". It's an anonymous class.

Comment: With the `{}`, you are actually creating an anonymous subclass.

Comment: yeah got that.I got confused . thanks all for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an anonymous subclass in your current code, but you are **very** close to having a functional interface. Let's change it to that, like

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Calculate {
    int multiply(int a, int b);
}
```

Now you have a *single abstract method* and can use fancy lambdas. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculate calc = (a, b) -> a * b;
    int result = calc.multiply(12, 32);
    System.out.println("result = " + result);
}
```

Note this is exactly like your original example, just syntactic sugar added with Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it multiply is not public to begin with. If you change your mulyiply method your Calculate class to

```java
public abstract int multiply(int a, int b);
```

then it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the calculate method is not in public scope, so you are not changing the scope.

```
abstract class Calculate {
     public abstract int multiply(int a, int b);
}

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = new Calculate() {
            @Override
             public int multiply(int a, int b) {
                return a * b;
            }
        }.multiply(11,11);
        System.out.println("result = " + result);
    }

}
```

The access level cannot be more restrictive than the overridden method's access level. For example: If the super class method is declared public then the overriding method in the subclass cannot be either private or protected.

Now there is a separate scope as default scope introduced in java , so you can call it as package private scope.

For rules of overriding in java you can follow the [Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Rules-for-Java-method-overriding)